# PHP PDO Help Required

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to fetch the UserID of the user that has just logged in and store it in $_SESSION['UserID'], however it is not doing so.

Doesn't store it. `Array ( [LoggedIn] => 1 [UserID] => )`

```
// Database Connection File
    require("../system/config.php");

    $user['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    $user['password'] = md5($_POST['password']);

    $login_check = $DBH->prepare("SELECT Username, Password FROM Users WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ?");
    $login_check->execute(array($user['username'], $user['password']));

    if(count($login_check) == 1) {
        session_start();
        $row = $login_check->fetch();
        $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = 1;
        $_SESSION['UserID'] = $row['UserID'];
        print_r($_SESSION);
    }

    else {
        echo "You have entered an incorrect Username and Password, please try again.";
    }
```

Comment: What happens or doesn't happen?

Comment: @Pekka Doesn't store the value: Array ( [LoggedIn] => 1 [UserID] => )

Comment: You are doing a `session_start()` before checking the value?

Comment: I only have one session start if thats what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** The answer you are probably looking for is that you aren't selecting `UserID` in your query. But you should still look at what I wrote below.

---

You'd should use `if ($login_check->rowCount() == 1)` instead of `count()`

Alternatively, it would be better to `fetch()` the password for the username and check it in php to see if it's correct because then you can detect and store bad password attempts for each user and possibly deny access for a while if there have been too many.

```
$login_check = $DBH->prepare("SELECT UserID, Password FROM Users WHERE Username = ?");
$login_check->execute(array($user['username']));
$row = $login_check->fetch();

if (!empty($row)) {
    // user exists
    if ($row['Password'] == $user['password']) {
        // login success
    }
    else {
        // bad password attempt
    }
}
else {
    // non-existant user
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, however on the PHP manual it says that rowCount shouldn't be used when the last statement is a SELECT - http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Comment: That's why I suggest the other method of just fetching it and checking if it's empty. I don't recommend `rowCount()` but it is at least a documented feature unlike using `count()` on the object. `rowCount()` does work with SELECTs on MySQL but is not recommended because it is not compatible with other databases if you were to switch to another but use the same php code.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Any idea why the UserID isn't being fetched from the database in the code I have provided above?

Comment: Simple answer: because you haven't specified it in your list of columns to grab in the mysql query. I missed that on first glance as well.

Comment: 'tis the first thing I noticed, but I've been working on DB code all day. :\